# Getting `InternalServerError` when creating Azure IoT Hub devices with bulk REST API with `createOrUpdate` mode

Tags: azure-iot-hub

I'm using [bulk device operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/deviceapi/bulkdeviceoperation#ImportMode) and `create` mode works fine but when using `createOrUpdate` mode API server returns HTTP code 500.
Is there any reason why I can't use `createOrUpdate`?

Comment: How did you test the `createOrUpdate` operation? I have tested with postman to post `createOrUpdate` request, it indeed does not work, the error shows **ErrorCode:ServerError;InternalServerError**.But the code in this link(https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/iot-hub/iot-hub-bulk-identity-mgmt.md) works.

Comment: Then seems like `createOrUpdate` works with *blob* bulk import. I've only tested on REST API from ruby with net/http.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply because i tried to involve somebody familiar with this problem. This issue has been opened internally.If there is any progress, i will let you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently Azure IoT Hub Device REST API does not support CreateOrUpdate mode in bulk operations, but only supports in Imports operation. I have given a feedback about the document to clarify this issue.